# Remove "view source" or "inspect element" selections from right-click menu

Tags: css, menu, right-click, selection-sort

I want to start selling html items online and want to include a live preview for the user but don't want the user to take the code by using the view source or inspect element selections from right-click menu. I need to remove them, is it possible? I prefer javascript/css/html solutions. (I'm not big on jquery or fiddle)

If not is there a way to link the code and secure the link?

Comment: No, this is of course not possible. Yes, you can try some amateurish tricks like “disable right click” altogether, but even that won’t work reliable in any browser. If you’re afraid your potential customers might “steal” your HTML code, then your only option is to not show it to them in the first place.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Anyone can just disable JavaScript and then your "protection" is gone. Plus, you can use the keyboard to view the source.

Comment: @CBroe I would like the amateur trick please.

Comment: use high quality print screens/images

Comment: Envato and other marketplaces protect your code. Did you take a look at the spurcecodes? Also, when you use PHP/AJAX, your original code is not fully visible, just the generated HTML code. How do you want to sell something when they can not try a real demo?

Comment: i would like them to try it in a demo.

Comment: Then you have to publish the HTML code. And there are always ways to prove that is it your own work ... http://notes.envato.com/authors/how-you-can-protect-your-copyright/

Comment: This is bound to fail, as is almost always the case when you try to solve a _legal_ issue through _technical_ matters. Apart from that, that you even ask this question makes me doubt your experience level in a way that I would say it’s likely fairly questionable if your HTML code is even worth “stealing” (or _selling_, for that matter).

Comment: @CBroe Its a 'custom' Audio Player and I've been learning how to make it for quite some time now, because of that i'd like to keep it secure. (I've worked for hours upon hours trying to get it to work, it does now, but can you see why i would want to hide it?)

Comment: I appreciate the answers - thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is about copyright protection, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work as view-source:// and opening the developer tools with pressing some keys on the keyboard still works ;-)